# Filter Out All Posts From Particular Craigslist Users

Tags: craigslist

Certain craigslist users in my area post constantly, legal posts, that I will never be interested in.  How do I filter out all posts on craigslist made by a handful of particular real users?

They haven't done anything wrong, I don't need to get them banned.

Is there some add-in extension for a browser that can do it?  Maybe one of you works for craigslist and could add this feature?  Maybe somebody knows how to make an add-in that could do it?

Comment: Should really check with Craigslist's rules, posting essentially similar ads repeatedly sounds like spam, if it's annoying there's probably a rule against it. Asking someone @Craigslist could help, and they should know better than anyone how to filter out ads you don't want to see too. Anyway an adblock/uBlock filter matching their username sounds appropriate